# Trouble with using groupby and ffill

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have pandas Dataframe:

```
Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4        id
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  NaT         2019-01-03   111
NaT         NaT         2019-01-02  NaT          111
2019-02-04  NaT         2019-02-05  2019-02-06   222
NaT         2019-02-08  NaT         NaT          222
```

I expect:

```
Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4        id
2019-01-01  2019-01-02  2019-01-02  2019-01-03   111
2019-02-04  2019-02-08  2019-02-05  2019-02-06   222
```

I tried to use:

`df  = df.groupby(['id']).fillna(method='ffill')`

But my process didn't execute for very long time.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: whats the shape of your data, column and row wise? also i think you should just `fffill` and `drop duplicates`, no need to use `groupby`

Answer (score 0):

The logic you want is `first`. This will take the first non-null value within group. Assuming those `NaT` indicate proper `datetime` columns:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).agg('first')
#    id      Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
#0  111 2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-03
#1  222 2019-02-04 2019-02-08 2019-02-05 2019-02-06
```

---

`ffill` is wrong because it returns a DataFrame indexed exactly like the original. Here you want an aggregation that collapses to one row per groupby key. Also `ffill` only **forward**-fills, though sometimes the value you want occur only on the second row.